# Sending Strings via UDP and writeUTF()

Tags: java

I have a simple UDP Server and Client. The server uses the `readInDataFile()`     method to populate the array list with all of the strings from a text file. My server can easily read the string from the bytes using  `"dis.readUTF();   "extracted = dis.readUTF();"`
and my Client easily writes them using `dis.writeUTF();`

I follow the same structure and logic to send the string that has been found from the array to the client, but it is not receiving anything.

*** My question: Why is the client not reading the string properly? I know that the server is reading in the year properly because I have a print statement to use the sent String and to go into the arrayList to determine what it is that we are going to print.

The .txt file that I am reading from has strings that start with 1875 all the way to 2011, so if the client typed in "2011" it would pass to the server and the server would go into the .txt file and retrieve "2011 Animal Kingdom John Velazquez 2:02.04"

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DerbyUDPClient {

    public InetAddress ip = null;

    // To print the string at the end
    String finalPrint = "";
    // Socket for UDP communication with server
    DatagramSocket dgs = null;
    DatagramSocket dgs2 = null;

    // The DataGramPacket used with server
    DatagramPacket dgp = null;
    DatagramPacket dgp2 = null;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;

    String year = "";

    // The String to hold the user's IP Address
    String ipString = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public DerbyUDPClient() throws IOException {
        getIPAddressServerAndYear();

    }

    public void getIPAddressServerAndYear() throws IOException {

        // Ask user for IP address, or they can just press return 
        System.out.println("Enter the IP Address of the server, please: ");
        ipString = input.nextLine();

        if (ipString.length() == 0) {

            ipString = "127.0.0.1";
        }

        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getByName(ipString);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Ask user for IP address, or they can just press return 
        System.out.println("Please enter a year between 1875 and 2011: ");

        year = input.nextLine();

        // Checks to see if the user has inputed a year 
        if (isInteger(year) == true) {

            // write and then receive

            dgs = new DatagramSocket();

            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

            dos.writeUTF(year);


            dgp = new DatagramPacket(bos.toByteArray(), bos.size());

            dgp.setAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            dgp.setPort(28150);

            dgs.send(dgp);

            // receive


            dgs.receive(dgp);

            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(dgp.getData());

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            finalPrint = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(finalPrint);

            dgs.close();
        }

    }

    public boolean isInteger(String input) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(input);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        new DerbyUDPClient();

    } // end main

} // end DerbyUDPClient


<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>><>><><><><>><><><> New class below
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DerbyUDPServer {

    // Socket for UDP communication with clients
    DatagramSocket dgs = null;
    DatagramSocket dgs2 = null;

    // The DataGramPacket used
    DatagramPacket dgp = null;

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

    int clientPort = 0;

    DatagramPacket dgp2 = null;

    // The string converted to an int is held in this variable
    int parsedString = 0;

    // Flag set to false when server should close
    boolean listening = true;

    // The String that is used to hold the extracted String
    String extracted = "";

    // Total number of clients server has sent data to
    int clientCount = 0;

    // Port number that server listens on
    static final int SERVER_PORT = 31250;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;

    // Array list containing a list of strings describing
    // Kentucky derby winners
    ArrayList<String> winners = new ArrayList<String>();

    public DerbyUDPServer() throws IOException {

        readInDataFile();
        handleClients();

    } // end DerbyUDPServer constructor

    protected void readInDataFile() throws IOException {
        int winIdx = 0;
        String singleWinner;

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("derby.txt"));

        while ((singleWinner = in.readLine()) != null) {

            winners.add(singleWinner);
            winIdx++;
        }

        in.close();

    } // end readInDataFile

    /*
     * Displays IP address and port number that clients can use to contact the
     * server to the console.
     */
    protected void displayContactInfo() {
        try {
            // Display contact information.
            System.out.println("Number Server standing by to accept Clients:"
                    + "\nIP : " + InetAddress.getLocalHost() + "\nPort: "
                    + dgs.getLocalPort() + "\n\n");

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // NS lookup for host IP failed?
            // This should only happen if the host machine does
            // not have an IP address.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } // end displayContactInfo

    public void handleClients() throws IOException {

        try {

            dgs = new DatagramSocket(28150);

            dgp = new DatagramPacket(new byte[50], 50);

        } catch (SocketException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        displayContactInfo();

        // Receive and then write

        // receive here

        dgs.receive(dgp);

        // Prints out the IP address and Port of the DataGramPacket 
        System.out.println(dgp.getAddress());
        System.out.println(dgp.getPort());

        // Extract the string from the bytes 

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(dgp.getData());

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        // Read in the string from the DataInputString...
        try {
            extracted = dis.readUTF();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // System.out.println("You entered the year: " + extracted);
        // Converts the String to an integer 
        parsedString = Integer.parseInt(extracted);

        // This below prints, so I am obviously receiving the integer year from the client

         System.out.println(getYearLine(parsedString));

        // Write below

        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        dos.writeUTF(getYearLine(parsedString));

        dgp2 = new DatagramPacket(bos.toByteArray(), bos.size());

        dgp2.setAddress(dgp.getAddress());
        dgp2.setPort(dgp.getPort());

        dgs.send(dgp2);

        while(listening == true){
            handleClients();
        }

    }

    public String getYearLine(int year) {

        if (year < 2012 && year > 1874) {

            return winners.get(2011 - year);

        } else {

            return "no derby info for that year";
        }

    } // getYearLine

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        new DerbyUDPServer();

    } // end main

} // end DerbyUDPServer
```

Comment: You forgot to say what is the actual string that your client receives. BTW Your client seems to be sending requests to localhost irrespective of the IP that was entered...

Comment: That is a lot of code. I would simplify the code and use String.getBytes("UTF-8") as that appears to be all you need

Comment: The client writes the year and then it receives a byte packet from the server. This byte packet that is received comes from the server and includes the string of text from the winners array. Then the client uses readUTF to change it from the bytes to a String.